# Fourier for periodic function

Tags: fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-x$ on the interval $[0,1)$, and extend $f$ to be periodic in $\mathbb R$. Show that $\mathcal{F}(0)=0$, and $\mathcal{F}(k)=(2\pi ik)^{-1}$, if $k\ne0$, where my $\mathcal{F}(k) = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\, e^{-2\pi i k x} \, \mathrm{d} x$.

---

I have proved that $\mathcal{F}(0)=0$, but for the other one, I am not able to as it needs two extra assumptions :

$(i)$ $k \in \mathbf Z$ $\And$

$(ii)$ The integral should be evaluated between just $0$ and $1$.

Can anyone explain me these two steps. Any type of help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The function $f$ is not integrable, are you sure that you did not mean the Fourier series? Are we talking distributions here?

Comment: yes i am sure that i need to evaluate the fourier transform. And it seems like the function is integrable, why did you said that it is not integrable

Comment: Because the function $f$ is not integrable on $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: it is integrable and however the integral will come out to be 0 even

Comment: $\int_0^1 |f(x)| dx = {1 \over 2}$, hence $\int_{-n}^n |f(x)| dx = n$, it follows from this that it is **not** integrable.

Comment: yes but you are taking the integral of $|f(x)|$ instead of $f(x)$

Comment: I give up. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: What should be emphasized here is that the Fourier transform in a case like this is not a _function_ but a _distribution_. The prototypical example of this is the so-called [Dirac comb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_comb), which is its own Fourier transform (and which is indeed not integrable in the sense of $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{-n}^n |f(x)|\,dx.$).